# Removing constraint from a model in gurobi c++

Tags: c++, gurobi

I have one constraint set

after some modification I have to remove this constraint:model.addConstr(LHS10_2 <= LHS10_1)set from the model. model.remove() is not working. How can I do it?
Thank for your help.

model.remove(LHS10_2 <= LHS10_1) can not work.

```
for (i = 1; i <= ULD; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= station; j++)
        {
            GRBLinExpr LHS10_1 = 0;//自載飛航節線
            GRBLinExpr LHS10_2 = 0;//他航載飛航節線
            for (k = 2; k <= load; k++)
            {
                if (k == 2 || k == 3 || k == 7)
                {
                    for (l = 1; l <= (node - 2); l++)
                    {
                        for (m = 1; m <= Num_FAn[j][k][l]; m++)
                        {
                            LHS10_1 += p*X[i][j][k][l][FSAn[j][k][l][m]][FLAn[j][k][l][m]][FNAn[j][k][l][m]];
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (k == 4 || k == 5)
                {
                    for (l = 1; l <= (node - 2); l++)
                    {
                        for (m = 1; m <= Num_FAn[j][k][l]; m++)
                        {
                            LHS10_2 += X[i][j][k][l][FSAn[j][k][l][m]][FLAn[j][k][l][m]][FNAn[j][k][l][m]];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            model.addConstr(LHS10_2 <= LHS10_1);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [GRBModel::addConstr()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/cpp_grbmodel_addconstr.html) returns an [GRBConstr](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/cpp_grbconstr.html) object that you should save in a local variable.  Then at a later point in time, you can use the [GRBModel::remove()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/cpp_grbmodel_remove.html) method to delete that particular constraint from the model again, i.e., you could do something like

```
// Array to hold added constraint objects
GRBConstr* c = new GRBConstr[nConstr];
for (int k = 0; k < nConstr, ++k) {
    // Create expressions LHS10_2 and LHS10_1 as needed
    // [...]
    // Add k-th constraint, grap object for later removal from model
    c[k] = model.addConstr(LHS10_2 <= LHS10_1);
}
// Do some stuff, optimize, etc.
// [...]
// now delete unwanted constraints from model
for (int k = 0; k < nConstr, ++k) {
    model.remove(c[k]);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your replication. But I tried your method, it is not effective.Do you have any method to solve this problem?  Thank you very much.

Comment: GRBConstr d;    
    
model.addConstr(LHS10_2 <= LHS10_1);
d = model.addConstr(LHS10_2 <= LHS10_1);                                                                   model.remove(d);                                                                                                                          mode.update();

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not effective"?  In the snipped you posted in the comment you add the same constraint `LHS10_2 <= LHS10_1` *twice*, hence after removing `d`, the first will persist.

Comment: Sorry,I did't explain the problem well. Because I want to delete constraints from this model.(ULD = 3,station = 10)Thus,there are totally thirty constraints for model.addConstr(LHS10_2 <= LHS10_1);The method you replied me  only can remove one constraint.So,I want to know how to delete these constraints.  I am grateful for your help.Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to remove multiple constraints from the model, you must keep track of *all* such constraints that you want to remove later.  I have updated my answer to cover that case.

Comment: Thank for your replication.I can remove the constraints successfully.But why the objective value will not change?Thank you very much.

Comment: It is perfectly possible that removing constraints (and resolving) does not alter the optimal objective value, or the solution.

Comment: @Robert when you iterate over nConstr, and always use if condition on that constraint, and if some condition is met you delete that constraint, will we ruin the constraint ordering? For example, I iterate over 3 constraints. I start from c1, delete it. Now if I call c[2] am I calling the original c[2] or c[3] since 1 is deleted?